# How to make localized site discoverable on SERP

Tags: seo, local-seo, internationalization, translation, localization

I localized my website more than a week ago in the hopes that the corresponding localized version would show up on the SERP. However, only the English version shows up, even though all pages have been crawled (checked by looking up site:milanfc.info). I have a valid sitemap with xhtml:link alternate links for each language as well as x-default as English. The head of the website also has the correct alternate links pointing to the localized versions of the site (including x-default again).

What do I need to do to make the localized site discoverable for a search in the corresponding country? I'm using Angular Universal for this project.

Here's the site: https://milanfc.info/en/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you have done so far is correct:

1. Created separate URLs for the content in different languages. (See [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization))
2. Put in hreflang meta tags.
3. Created XML sitemaps of the language URLs. (Although XML sitemaps have little to do which which pages Google chooses to index, see [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox))
4. Put a menu of links on your site so that every page has links the other languages.

There are only a few more things you can do:

1. Get external links to your new pages.  Google will be more likely to index your content in multiple languages if you get language appropriate links.  For example, external German sites linking to your German content.
2. Use the Google Search Console URL Inspection Tool to do a live test on your new pages.  Make sure that Googlebot can fetch the pages and render them to see the content.
3. Wait.   It can sometimes take Google a couple months to index new content.  This is especially true when you are using JavaScript reliant frameworks like Angular.   Using such frameworks often makes indexing months slower than it would otherwise be with non-JavaScript, plain HTML based sites.