# Google Search is displaying French version of my website even though I'm in the U.S

Tags: google-search, local-seo

I have a website that has dual language toggle to serve English Canadian and French Canadian. I am based in U.S.A. and when I google my website, the version with the French translation is the one that shows up. How can I fix this?

Here is a screenshot:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

Without more information, it is not easy to say why you're seeing the French version of the page in your search results. Do you have hreflang implemented on the site?

For help you might review Google's [hreflang documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions)

Hreflang is a way to tell search engines not only which language, but which regions, the content on your site is written for. [Yoast](https://yoast.com/hreflang-ultimate-guide/) also has a good write up.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the language switching option on your site, it doesn't change the URL.  If you want Google to index your website in multiple languages properly you **MUST** use different URLs for different languages.   For example you could have:

- `bsgcanada.com/en` and `bsgcanada.com/fr`
- or `en.bsgcanada.com/` and `fr.bsgcanada.com/`

When you base the language of the page on the geographic IP address of the user or on the user's `Accept-Language` header, search engine bots won't be able to crawl both language versions of your site.   You can't tell search engine bots to crawl your site twice from different locations or with different `Accept-Language` headers.

For full details about how to set your site up see [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization).

The inner pages of your site are a little bit better.  You have localized the URL path.  For example you have `/about-us` and `/à-propos-de-nous` which serve the same purpose in two different languages.   These could be made OK for SEO.

- Implement [hreflang](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions) tags between the two.
- Ensure that both can be crawled from anywhere in the world with any `Accept-Language` headers.   Right now you sometimes redirect between the two.   For example from the US I see:

  ```
  $ curl --head https://bsgcanada.com/%C3%A0-propos-de-nous
  HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
  Location: https://bsgcanada.com/about-us
  ```