# I want to redirect 301 to an added query string

Tags: htaccess, redirects

I do want to 301 redirect `https://example.com/no/` and all the URLs from that catalogue with an added query string `?lang=no`. For example will then url `https://example.com/no/about/` be `https://example.com/no/about/?lang=no`

Is it easiest to do that solution via .htaccess, and how can I do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  Then the language code is duplicated in the URL and the URL looks a lot worse.  Using language parameters is also not recommended for SEO, see [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization)

Comment: Hi, I do have set up a multisite structure site using Wordpress/ woocommerce. I need it to be multisite structure since I have different api integration for different directories. Example.com/sv/ is like a separate site, example.com/en/ is like another separate site. The only options I do find for plugins to automatically translate the sites is for them to add a extra slug like /no/no/ or as a subdomain .no.example.com/no/ none of that seems good. I then thought about parameter instead, but then example.com/no/ is used to translate to the correct language when added the parameter

Comment: But maybe it is then better to have no.example.com/no/ as the structure for the SEO pint of view?