# Geolocation Redirect Popup SEO

Tags: seo, geolocation

What is the correct SEO way of redirecting customers to other websites based on their IP? We currently have 2 websites, one is for brazil and one is for other Latin America. The 2 websites are different aside from language, hosted both on Shopify but not the same account,  the brazil website only shows a few products and has a different design.

My method of redirecting is using GeoIP API, then show pop up asking them that there is a brazil website available and asking them if they want to proceed or stay.

Just want to ask what should we do for its SEO and if it will have a negative impact on our websites. Do we need to declare ref lang and country?

Comment: +1 for asking users if they want to stay vs automatically redirecting them.  Geo IP databases are wrong a significant portion of the time and also don't account for foreign language speakers that need to use one site or the other because it is in their language.  Related question: [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization)

Comment: What is the alternative for GEO IP? The store is hosted in Shopify so I have limited capability on its server-side.

Answer (score 1):

From **[Google's point of view](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/managing-multi-regional-sites?hl=en#let-the-user-switch-the-page-language)**, redirecting users based on IP is a bad practice for SEO:

> Avoid automatic redirection based on the user's perceived language.
> These redirections could prevent users (and search engines) from
> viewing all the versions of your site.

and further in the same guideline:

> Do not use IP analysis to adapt your content. IP location analysis is
> difficult and generally not reliable. Furthermore, Google may not be
> able to crawl variations of your site properly. Most, but not all,
> Google crawls originate from the US, and we do not attempt to vary the
> location to detect site variations. Use one of the explicit methods
> shown here (hreflang, alternate URLs, and explicit links).