# Creating a multilingual page or two different versions of a page?

Tags: seo, html, multilingual, translation

My website is totally in turkish language.

But I needed a page `example.php` to be both turkish and english.

I am planning on creating 2 different versions like `example_tr.php`, and `example_en.php`.

The images will all be same, only the text will be different.

Is there any flaws in this approach from SEO perspective?

Comment: Related: [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization)

Comment: If you didn't create two different versions, how would your URLs be structured?

Comment: I thought of creating a single page using a solution like accept language header. I guess this way there won't be multiple urls, no multiple pages, so no need to structure. After reading your post, seems like the best solution is to create a subdirectory.

Comment: Search engines don't support multiple languages hidden behind an accept-language header.  Differentiating the URLs is best.  It is pretty common to use rewrite rules to make the URLs look they way you want without having to duplicate code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only flaw would be that `_` is not a Google-recommended separator for filenames. Unless there are technical reasons to use `_`, it is better to use `-` instead.

This has historical reasons and Google employees have been unclear on weather `_` is now equal to `-` or not. So bets practice is to stick with `-`.

Also, if you expect to have multiple pages in both English and Turkish, using subdirectories would be *cleaner*: `/en/example.php` and `/tr/example.php`. Or in your case, you could simply add `/en/` as a subdirectory for English content and leave the rest of the site as it is.

*"Cleaner"*, in this case, means it is easier for Google to understand that one part of your website is English and another Turkish. It also makes it easier for you to segment the data in Google Search Console, Google Analytics, and virtually any other tool.

Edit: To clarify, if you want to rank in both languages, you must have a separate URL (page) for each language. You cannot have both languages on the URL (page).

Comment: Can you add your opinion on creating 1 multilingual single page vs 2 seperate pages?  Thank you