# Is it good practice to create separate HTML files for each language when building a multi-language website?

Tags: url, multilingual, site-structure, filenames

I'm new to web development and am curious about the standard practice regarding multi-language websites.

Suppose I want to build a website on which one can toggle the language by clicking a button.

Would it be better to make separate HTML files for the two different languages and make it so that clicking the button redirects the user to the corresponding file? Or would it be better to create blocks of code for each language in the same HTML file and toggle between them?
If one approach is better than the other, why so?

Comment: This may answer some of your questions.  [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization)  With rewriting, how you structure URLs isn't necessarily how your code has to be structured though.

Comment: Yes, the linked post was quite helpful. Thank you!